# Future continuous in the main clause of first conditional

Tags: conditionals, future-continuous

I have read [this page](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1bqZBhDXARIsANTjCPKqULRFGc51vIRRAkNvhyo_alE3FTi64RKCQVa79QxREHArT7YSd6QaAmaLEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)  and [this page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if). In both, for the first conditional, there are just examples in which simple future is used in the main clause.

Can we use future continuous in the main clause as well?

Example:

Simple future version:

> 1. The film that I watched yesterday was very good and if I have time, I **will watch** it again in the future.

Future continuous version:

> 2. The film that I watched yesterday was very good and if I have time, I **will be watching** it again in the future.

Is there any difference between these two sentences or the meaning they convey is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both correct and natural.

One function of "will" + continuous is to add *the nuance of enjoyment or dread*. So, where "***I'll do** X again*" is a simple statement about the future, "***I'll be doing** X again*" implies that doing X will either be repeated because it was so enjoyable, or repeated despite it being dreadful.

Your example sentence shows enjoyment. Here's one that shows dread:

> I failed geography, so I guess **I'll be taking it again** this summer.

The version without the continuous is just a reasonable statement about the future without nuances of feeling:

> I failed geography, so I guess **I'll take it again** this summer.

Comment: This question is not related to my original question but your answer have raised a question for me. Why have you said:  "despite it *being* dreadful". What kind of structure is it? Is it just because we need a noun phrase after "despite"? Isn't it more naturally to say: "although it is dreadful"?

Comment: @alireza "it being dreadful" is a *gerund phrase*. Gerunds are nouns. Here's that phrase in subject position: "*It was raining and windy on the bike ride home, but **it being dreadful** didn't stop me from getting there.*"